# Problems with kohana and HTTPS

Tags: https, kohana

I have changed my domain in HTTPS, but after this change my website (developed in kohana) don't work fine.

Any element (image, css, link, etc.) is in HTTP, not in HTTPS.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [URL::base()](https://koseven.dev/documentation/api/URL#base) function. Kohana automatically detect protocol.

So, if you use some (reverse)proxy to http server, this can happen.

Or in code you have forced to use **http** (`URL::base()`, `URL::site()`.

You can overwride this by adding `application/classes/URL.php` file

```php
class URL extends Kojana_URL {
  public static function base($protocol = NULL, $index = FALSE){
    return self::base('https', $index);
  }
}
```